# Google Map API billing to Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session

Tags: google-maps, billing

I need to autocomplete a Country and City fields for my responsive website.
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#ac-no-details-session

A bit confused with billing options. Wish to understand if I'm charged for that.
https://scrnli.com/RN0ZXJfh6T4OAw
I see 0.00 USD Price per SESSION in the grid, but 0.017 USD per session in the last line.

I'd be much obliged if you could clarify what are the free option limits.

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete response does not include the country or city. This requires a second call to place details using the same session token.

1. AutoComplete using sessiontoken -> place_id
2. Get details using place_id, [sessiontoken](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#sessiontoken), and specifying only the [fields](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#fields) you need.

Please note there is a $200/monthly credit of maps platform usage. https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-credits#monthly